# Eliminating rule of existential quantifier

Tags: logic

Why is the rule $\begin{array}{c}
\exists x(\varphi(x))\quad \forall x (\varphi(x)\rightarrow A)\\
\hline
A
\end{array}$ valid? Why does this rule hold? How can one verify this rule *intuitively*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement $\exists x (\varphi(x))$ says that there is some value of $x$ for which $\varphi(x)$ is true. Fix such a value of $x$, say $a$. We now know that $\varphi(a)$ is true.

The statement $\forall x (\varphi(x) \to A)$ says that whenever you substitute a value for $x$ into the formula $\varphi(x) \to A$, what you get is a true statement. So, substituting $a$ for $x$, we now know that $\varphi(a) \to A$ is true.

Since $\varphi(a)$ and $\varphi(a) \to A$ are both true, by modus ponens it follows that $A$ is true.

Comment: You proved the rule $\begin{array}{c}
\exists x(\varphi(x))\quad \forall x (\varphi(x)\rightarrow A)\\
\hline
A
\end{array}$. But in the calculus of natural deduction it is an inference rule that is assumed to be true. In the calculus of natural deduction one can't give constant symbols like you do (you add a constant symbol 'a' to the system). Is it natural to add new constant symbols?

Comment: First you say to do it "intuitively", which Clive's answer does.  Then you say "But" and object to that.

Comment: Probably I did not express myself well. Clive's answer is perfectly valid. Thanks for that.